# python find cluster membership in graph

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

In python I am trying to solve them same problem I previously had in R:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({"id1": [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,np.NaN,np.NaN],
                   "id2": ['a',np.NaN,'a','c','c','d','x',np.NaN,'y','z','x','z',np.NaN,np.NaN],
                   "id3": [1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,np.NaN,np.NaN]})
```

I want python to compute column `id3`, i.e. assign the network cluster membership (ideally ignoring NAs)

in R:

```
g <- graph_from_data_frame(df, FALSE)
cg <- clusters(g)$membership
df$id4 <- cg[df$id1]
df
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can generate a undirected `networkx` graph with source and destination set to `id1` and `id2`, then `enumerate` over the connected components in the graph to create a mapping dictionary and `map` this dictionary on `id1` column

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df.dropna(), 'id1', 'id2')
df['id3'] = df['id1'].map({c: i for i, cc in enumerate(
                           nx.connected_components(G), 1) for c in cc})
```

---

```
    id1  id2  id3
0   1.0    a  1.0
1   1.0  NaN  1.0
2   2.0    a  1.0
3   2.0    c  1.0
4   3.0    c  1.0
5   3.0    d  1.0
6   4.0    x  2.0
7   4.0  NaN  2.0
8   5.0    y  2.0
9   5.0    z  2.0
10  6.0    x  2.0
11  6.0    z  2.0
12  NaN  NaN  NaN
13  NaN  NaN  NaN
```